# How to remove role="navigation" from all nav elements?

Tags: php, navigation, seo, validation

I did a W3C validation of my wordpress website and I got several warnings like this:

```
The navigation role is unnecessary for element nav.

r">↩ <nav role="navigation" class="elementor-nav-menu--main elementor-nav-menu__container elementor-nav-menu--layout-horizontal e--pointer-none"><ul id
```

**My doubts:**
Is this role really necessary?
I know that this may be necessary for older browsers that don't recognise HTML5 elements, but I think that this may affect websites pagerank. I read that Google penalizes your pagerank when you have warnings in your HTML.

In case these warnings affect the pagerank, I wonder if there is a way to deactivate/remove this attribute from all  elements, so like that I could have a validation without any error or warning.

Comment: I don't know Google's algorithm, but I feel very confident in saying that Google is not going to penalise you for this. That would be absurd. Regardless, the affected element appears to be from Elementor, so you'd need to ask it's developers, as 3rd-party plugins are off topic here.